# Class is not correctly reading argument in constructor function

Tags: javascript, class, parameter-passing

I should build a `class` User which should contain:
a target `property` which equals `first argument` of `constructor` function.
An `activated` property set to `false`.
An instance function, called `activate`, whichs sets `activated` to `true`.
An instance function `use` returning  value of instance target if `activated` property is set to `true`. Otherwise `undefined`.

I got the error: "It looks like your User *(Class-Name)* is not correctly reading it's target from the constructor function."

And I don't know, what this means. This is my code so far:

```
class User {
  constructor(target) {
    this.activated = false;
    this.activate = () => {
      this.activated = true;
    }
    this.use = () => {
      if (this.activated == true) {
        console.log(target);
      } else {
        console.log(false);
      }
    }
  }
}

const m = new User('Kevin');
m.activate(); // Because this.activated is set to true …
m.use(); // Output is target which is 'Kevin'
```

**So I don't understand, why  I miss the test**

Because of part of the task is asking for:
"a target `property` which equals `first argument` of `constructor` function."
I thought of setting …

```
class User {
  constructor(name) {
```

and do this …

```
this.name = target
```

… would solve the issue.

But I got:

```
ReferenceError: target is not defined
```

Maybe it's due to a lack of understanding English but **I have no idea, what I miss here.** Because I got the desired output:
When I run  `m.activate();` before `m.use();` I got "Kevin" otherwise `false`

Comment: Did you declare the variable you are using inside the constructor?

Comment: You are not setting the `target` parameter to any property. Set `this.target = target` in the constructor and `console.log(this.target)` inside the function

Comment: thank you @deceze it is m.use() ; :)

Comment: @AdilRaza I hope I got your question right: Yes, I declared everything inside the constructor  – there is no further code.

Comment: @S.H Did you solve the problem?

Comment: @adiga Thank you! You and Leccles1 helped me solving this …

Comment: I'm confused what exactly you want to achieve. I tried running your code and I got no errors. https://jsfiddle.net/anfLd26k/1/

Comment: @Adil Raza Yes, thank you

Answer (score 1):

In your second attempt.

```
class User {
  constructor(name) {
```

Your constructor parameter is called 'name' but you're trying to set;

```
this.name = target
```

Try changing to;

```
this.name = name;
```

You'll need to update your 'use' function accordingly so that it reads the name from the property `this.name` set at the start of the constructor.

Comment: and adiga, thank you very much, you solutions helped me.